# Code to remove timestamp from all filenames in a folder

Tags: python

Hi All been looking around this forum for what I want but cant find anything. Very new to python do be gentle lol. Using python 2

I have a bunch of filenames in a folder like:

```
[Dog]test 2021-04-01 22-12-01.txt
[Dog]test2 2021-02-01 22-22-01.txt
[Dog]test3 2020-05-01 22-23-21.txt
[Dog]test4 2020-02-07 22-22-31.txt
```

What im trying to do is make all the files look like this:

```
test.txt
test2.txt
test3.txt
test4.txt
```

I found some code to remove a keyword and also something else to remove a number of characters but it wouldn't do everything i wanted.

Cheers

Edit: Say the filenames didnt all start with the same [Dog] say it was [Dog] [Cat] [Bird] Then the filename.txt
Also is there a way to direct to all files in a folder rather then writing all the filenames in the code?

Comment: extract all the file names into a list then use a regular expression to remove the date time information and replace it with blank then rename the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your files start with '[dog]' and are txt format, then you can simply skip the first 5 characters, split the file on the spaces, use the first part ([0]), then manually add '.txt'. But only works if the files are formatted like you said.

```
data = ['[Dog]test 2021-04-01 22-12-01.txt',\
        '[Dog]test2 2021-02-01 22-22-01.txt',\
        '[Dog]test3 2020-05-01 22-23-21.txt',\
        '[Dog]test4 2020-02-07 22-22-31.txt']
    
new_data = [file[5:].split(' ')[0] + '.txt' for file in data]
```

**EDIT**

To replace the data list to a directory listing you can use:

```
import os

path = r"C:\user\folder"
data = os.listdir(path)

#Unedited
print(data)

new_data = [file[5:].split(' ')[0] + '.txt' for file in data]

#Edited
print(new_data)
```

Comment: thanks for that. Maybe all the files don't start with the same, say it was:

Comment: @kodiUser if this was what you were looking for, then please accept the answer with the tick symbol :)

Comment: What about if there were alot more files, in this instance would i have to type out all the filenames first or could i just add a directory listing?

Comment: If all files are stored in the folder you can use os.listdir(folderpath). Please check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-listdir-method/

Comment: Ive got it to print out the list but im not sure how to insert the code you mentioned. this is what i Have: `code`import os 
  
path = "C:\\Users\\ED\\Desktop\\testsource"
dir_list = os.listdir(path) 
  
print("Files and directories in '", path, "' :")  

print(dir_list) `code`

Comment: Please check my edit above. This should work, again if all files in the folder are txt files. Otherwise you need additional statements to just filter out those.

Comment: That works perfect. Now I need to actually rename the files :)

Answer (score 0):

If all the files are in the exact format then this will work.

```
var = 'test2 2021-04-01 22-12-01.txt'.split()
print(var[0]+var[2][var[2].index('.'):])  # prints test2.txt
```